# Access to XMLHttpRequest at In Asp.net core 2.2.1

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

In my Asp.net core project, I use  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App Version="2.2.1" 
and  call AddCors in Startup service 
`Startup.cs` :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                );
    });

    .....

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors(policyName: "CorsPolicy");  

            ....
```

`Controller` :

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
    public class ManageUsersController : Controller
    { ...
```

In angular 5 App when calling Web API show this error in the console of the browser

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:5000/api/Account/LoginByPortal' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the
>   wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

angular service :

```
loginByPortal(credentials: Credentials): Observable<userLoginViewmodel> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http
      .post(`${this.appConfig.apiEndpoint}/Account/LoginByPortal`, credentials,
       { headers: headers, withCredentials: true /* For CORS */ })     
      .map(response => response || {})
      .catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => Observable.throw(error));
  }
```

I don't want to use `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200"` 
I want to use AllowAnyOrigin In CoresPloicy 
What's the problem? How can I solve It?

Comment: Either remove `AllowCredentials` or specify an origin.

Comment: @Sasan Remove AllowCredentials but show error again

Comment: What about that `withCredentials: true` ?

Comment: Could you please provide asp.net core log

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53790841/8801075

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                .AllowCredentials()
            );
```