# ASP.NET Core webpage ignores CORS policy in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-2.1

This is not a duplicate of previous questions, because their solutions say to add a CORS policy.  My question here is about why that CORS policy is being ignored in this case, despite its presence.

---

I'm getting a basic ASP.NET Core 2.1 webpage going, which will communicate with a docker container running at `localhost:5082`.  (Yes, .NET Core 2.1's a little old, but it's a necessary evil for us at the moment, for departmental-type reasons.)

So naturally, when trying to run that webpage project through the Visual Studio debugger, the AJAX request on the page fails when trying to access that container, because of the CORS policy. So...I've gone in to `Startup.cs` and added a very liberal CORS policy, and for some reason, it's getting ignored.

I've tried several similar posts and SO answers, which are all doing very similar things, but this is an example of what my Startup.cs might look like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace TheNamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                    });
            });
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseCors("AllowAll");
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the calls to `services.AddCors` and `app.UseCors`.  Different posts and SO answers have slightly different expressions of this, but they all point to having a `Startup.cs` that is very similar to this.

But this is getting ignored somehow, and my very basic JavaScript `GET` call to `http://localhost:5082/...` is still failing with this error message:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5082/... (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

What's wrong?

---

This is the JavaScript that's failing (`url` is a string value):

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open('GET', url, false);
//xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
xmlHttp.send(null);
return xmlHttp.responseText;
```

---

**EDIT:**

This is not an MVC project or anything fancy at all.  When creating the project, I just selected the option for `Web Application`.  So right now, it doesn't have controllers, just pages.

---

**EDIT:**

Per the comments, this is basically my project structure:

```
Pages:
    Shared:
        _CookieConsentPartial.cshtml
        _Layout.cshtml
        _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml
    _ViewImports.cshtml
    _ViewStart.cshtml
    Index.cshtml
Program.cs
Startup.cs
```

In terms of the URL, it's `http://localhost:5082/api/buildcactus`.

Comment: Try moving the "app.UseCors("AllowAll");" above the "app.UseStaticFiles();" call

Comment: Looks like it's running into the same problem.  Thanks though.

Comment: I know you said you're using 2.1, but just double-check - in 2.2 there was a change that means allowing everything for CORS no longer works: https://trailheadtechnology.com/breaking-change-in-aspnetcore-2-2-for-signalr-and-cors/

Comment: I think it would help if you showed your actual project structure, as well as the actual URL you're invoking.

Comment: Ahhh... what is the HTTP status code you're getting when your JS tries to hit your endpoint?

Comment: To expand on my previous comment: in ASP.NET Core 2.1, the exception-handling middleware would clear all HTTP headers, **including CORS headers**, when an exception occurred in the request pipeline **and was not explicitly handled**. This was fixed in 2.2: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2378#issuecomment-405096602

Comment: @IanKemp Thanks.  It looks like it's not even making the call.  The status code shows as `0` leading up to `xmlHttp.send(null);`, and then it just throws an Error.

Comment: @Panzercrisis The CORS issue may be confusing `XMLHttpRequest`. Have a look in Chrome's developer console, there should be an `OPTIONS` request to your endpoint - what status code is that returning?

Comment: Actually, I don't think you even need to do that. `api/buildcactus` doesn't exist so it will either throw a 404 or a 500, both of which should go through the exception handling middleware. So your problem, to put it simply, is that you're trying to access something that doesn't exist.

Comment: @IanKemp For some reason, I can't seem to find the Options request.  I'm able to pull the the URL up in my browser and in Postman though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SignalR Core 2.2 CORS AllowAnyOrigin() breaking change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786977/signalr-core-2-2-cors-allowanyorigin-breaking-change)

Comment: @MarkusDeibel Thanks.  I tried Alexandre's answer out, but it produced the same result basically.